# Following redirects internally with Varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to implement a rubygems reverse proxy using Varnish 4.1. Clients inside my intranet do not have a general outbound NAT, so I need Varnish to internally follow all redirects, preferably caching both the 302 from rubygems.org and the response from the CDN server.

Here's my default.vcl:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

backend default {
    .host = "rubygems.org";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    std.syslog(180, "doing vcl_recv");
    std.syslog(180, "req.url = " + req.url);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    std.syslog(180, "doing vcl_deliver");
    std.syslog(180, "resp.status = " + resp.status);
    if (resp.status == 302) {
        set req.url = resp.http.Location;
        std.syslog(180, "restarting with req.url = " + req.url);
        return(restart);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    std.syslog(180, "doing vcl_backend_fetch");
    std.syslog(180, "bereq.retries = " + bereq.retries);
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
    std.syslog(180, "doing vcl_backend_error");
}
```

If I `curl -i http://localhost/latest_specs.4.8.gz`, Varnish throws an HTTP 503 and logs the following:

```
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_recv
varnishd[20384]: req.url = /latest_specs.4.8.gz
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_backend_fetch
varnishd[20384]: bereq.retries = 0
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_deliver
varnishd[20384]: resp.status = 302
varnishd[20384]: restarting with req.url = http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_recv
varnishd[20384]: req.url = http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_backend_fetch
varnishd[20384]: bereq.retries = 0
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_deliver
varnishd[20384]: resp.status = 302
varnishd[20384]: restarting with req.url = http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_recv
varnishd[20384]: req.url = http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_backend_fetch
varnishd[20384]: bereq.retries = 0
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_deliver
varnishd[20384]: resp.status = 302
varnishd[20384]: restarting with req.url = http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_recv
varnishd[20384]: req.url = http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_backend_fetch
varnishd[20384]: bereq.retries = 0
varnishd[20384]: doing vcl_deliver
varnishd[20384]: resp.status = 302
varnishd[20384]: restarting with req.url = http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
```

It does not seem to be requesting the new URL even after updating req.url and restarting the request.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer but here are some thoughts:

1) "req.url" holds only the path part of a URL but does not contain the protocol and host part of an URL. So it seems plain wrong to me when you assign "http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz" to "req.url" in vcl_deliver and then restart.

In my opinion the restarted request will not hit "rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net" but still "rubygems.org" - the defined default backend.

So I guess you would need to define a second backend "rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net" and and set when you restart. You also need to do something like this (not tested)

```
set resp.http.Location = regsub(resp.http.Location,"^http://","");
set req.http.host = regsub(resp.http.Location,"/.*$","");
set req.url = regsub(resp.http.Location,"[^/]*","");
```

2) retry and restart are different concepts in varnish 4

That is why bereq.retries always shows 0. You need to look at req.restarts